# Merge two tables into one pivot table - order of columns is different

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I saw how to merge two different tables into one pivot but they all had the same order of columns. I have two different excel sheets from two different DBs and I want to merge both into one pivot - they have the same column names but in different order.
Attached is the screen shot of the first table, the second table and the pivot table I would like to have

[image]

Comment: Maybe this may help: https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Consolidate-multiple-worksheets-into-one-PivotTable-report-3ae257d2-ca94-49ff-a481-e9fc8adeeeb5

Comment: @Mukul215 I read it before I came here, naturally. It doesn't talk about different column order

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer! 
One should just attach both tables one right or left to each other and create a pivot table from one source rather multiple.
However, excel then differentiates between A1 and A1_1 for the second table. To solve this I used calculated fields for a new field of A1 and A1_1.